# Hoffman and Kunze Chapter 3 Theorem 9

Tags: linear-algebra

> Theorem 9. Let $V$ and $W$ be finite dimensional vector spaces over the field $F$ such that $\dim V=\dim W.$ If $T$ is a linear transformation from $V$ into $W,$ the following are equivalent:
>
> (i) If $\{\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n\}$ is basis for $V,$ then $\{T\alpha_1,\ldots,T\alpha_n\}$ is a basis for $W.$
> (ii) There is some basis $\{\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n\}$ for $V$ such that $\{T\alpha_1,\ldots,T\alpha_n\}$ is a basis for $W.$

Can someone explain me the difference between the two statements. I seem to understand the difference when I read it but the fact that I won't be able to articulate this to someone else is bothering me real bad.

Comment: The first statement says for every basis of $V$ ...

Comment: The second statement says that there is at least one basis of $V$ such that ...

Comment: Clearly, the first statement implies the second one. The claim of the  theorem is that also, the second statement implies the first.

Answer (score 1):

The first statement is the assertion that *for every* basis $\{ \alpha_1, \dotsc, \alpha_n \}$ for $V$, the set $\{ T\alpha_1, \dotsc, T\alpha_n \}$ is a basis for $W$.

The second statement is the assertion that *there exists some* basis $\{ \alpha_1, \dotsc, \alpha_n \}$ for $V$ such that the set $\{ T\alpha_1, \dotsc, T\alpha_n \}$ is a basis for $W$.

Definitely if the first assertion is true, then so is the second, since every vector space has a basis. The important content of the theorem is that the converse is also true.